# Exchange Server 2016 - identify full hybrid and/or minimal hybrid using or not

Tags: powershell, exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchange-hybrid

We have 2 Exchange Server 2016. I want to check it if I am using Full Hybrid and / or minimal hybrid in our environment.
What should I understand from the following output?

get-hybridconfiguration output:

```
Features                  : {FreeBusy, MoveMailbox, Mailtips, MessageTracking, OwaRedirection, OnlineArchive,
                            SecureMail, CentralizedTransport, Photos}
```

Comment: Any updates? If your issue has been resolved, you could mark the helpful reply as best answer if someone encounters the same issue, they could find the solution quickly:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the returned results, you have developed full hybrid in your organization, the reason are listed below:
[image]

Minimal hybrid migrations are best for medium-sized organizations that have a few hundred to a couple thousand mailboxes and want to finish their migration within a couple months. Like full hybrid, minimal hybrid migrations set up on-going Active Directory synchronization with Microsoft 365 and Office 365 to help with recipient administration. However, features like free/busy synchronization and other enhanced features aren't available.

For more details: [Exchange hybrid deployment features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/exchange-hybrid#exchange-hybrid-deployment-features) and [What options will I have when I run the migration advisor?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-migration-jump#what-options-will-i-have-when-i-run-the-migration-advisor)